# MySQL Determine which condition was satisfied

Tags: mysql, sql, select, syntax

I was wondering if there is way to store where clause conditions and not calculate them more than once in order to determine which one was satisfied.
Here is what I am talking about:
`select col, col1>5 cond1, col2<400 cond2 from table where col1>5 or col2<400`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should worry about calculating the simple comparisons like `col1 > 5` more than once *for each row*, but in order to save typing in a more complex query, you *may* do like this:

```
SELECT col, col1 > 5 AS cond1, col2 < 400 AS cond2
FROM table
HAVING cond1 or cond2
```

Using `having` instead of `where` gives access to the aliases introduced in the `select` clause.

Comment: +1..Exactly what I wanted :) Typing it twice is the main reson